# Swift: parsing .js file

Tags: swift, string

I have a `.js` file with the following format.

```
var *nameOfVar1*=new Array(*Int*, *Int*, ..., *Int*);
var *nameOfVar2*=new Array(\'*String*\', \'*String*\', ...,\'*String*\');...
```

In swift I want to put all values from file to corresponding array. What's the best way to do that? Do I use enumerateSubstrings?

```
var nameOfVar1 = [Int]()
var nameOfVar2 = [String]()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format is that simple and *really* consistent (e.g. always has the spaces at the same locations), you can come pretty far with simple string manipulation, e.g. using the following steps:

- split the file content into an array of lines, then for each line ...
- cut off the first 4 chars to get rid of `var`
- find the index of `=` to cut out the substring representing the variable's name
- again cut off the leading chars to get rid of `=new Array(`
- remove the trailing `)`
- the remaining string now only contains values (Ints or Strings) and commas, so now is the time to use `split(separator: ", ")` to get the single values
- numeric values of course have to be parsed into Ints using `Int(stringNum)`
- string values on the other hand have to be stripped of the leading and trailing quotes

If the format is *not* 100% consistent or is more complicated than you showed in your example, you should have a look at the `Scanner` class; a great simple example can be found [here](http://nshipster.com/nsscanner/).

---

**EDIT**: Converting Strings to Ints

To convert the String array you can use `map`:

```
nameOfVar1 = values.components(separatedBy: ",").map { Int($0)! }
```

Note: I think when splitting the values string into arrays (both for String and Int values) you should use `", "` (a comma followed by a space) as separator because in your example that's the used format.

Comment: Please look at code above